# AWS Lambda - Is there a way to Debug Aws lambda function localy?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

Im working on a lambda function that get's triggered from Kinesis streams.
I'm new to the aws kind of stuff so im just wondring if there is a way to debug localy the lambda function !
What i'm doing right now is every time i want to test i need to deploy on integration invirenement and it's kind of painefull and time consuming.

The function is built using java8.

Any propositions please !!

Comment: Depends what your function is doing.

Comment: reading from Kinesis stream and inserting data into a database

Comment: Sounds like you might need to mock a DB connection.

Comment: You can try approach described in https://sookocheff.com/post/kinesis/local-development-with-the-kcl/ to run kinesis locally and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/tke-sam-local.html to run lambda locally